# self-destructive OverlayEntry flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create an OverlayEntry which covers the entire screen. How then, may I remove this OverlayEntry, if the only widget on the screen is the OverlayEntry. Basically, I am asking, how can the OverlayEntry unmount itself.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the only widget on screen?

Comment: The property opaque, is set to true.